# how to install cjax in codeigniter 3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i had a problem
i use codeigniter 3.0.6 and my server is lampp with PHP Version 5.5.38
i want use cjax 5.9 in codeigniter but when i merge ci and cjax and i go to this url:http://localhost/ci_ajax/ajax.php?test/test
i see this error
Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/ci_ajax/cjax/ajax.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci_ajax/ajax.php on line 32

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ci_ajax/cjax/ajax.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci_ajax/ajax.php on line 32
can you help me?
sorry for bad english typing and tanks

Comment: first of all if you are using Linux os you need to set permission of folder eg 755,777 command is chmod -R 777 /foldterpath

Comment: tanks for your answer but my permission is 777(for lampp and htdocs and ci_ajax folder )